# How to efficiently return data from different columns and rows in same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, group-by

I have a transaction table that looks like the below, showing products being produced and then removed as they are scanned to an order. I would like to show both products that have and haven't been scanned to an order yet, without listing every transaction in the table. I went from a 1 second simple select, to a 10-minute select with a single sub-query.

Is there a better way for me to be doing this?

I am running Microsoft SQL Server 2017 and cannot modify the table structure as it is linked to a proprietary production system. I don't believe I can aggregate as there are other text fields to be returned.

#### Select sub-query (very slow)

```
SELECT
    Unique,
    Weight,
    ProductionDate,
    ProductCode,
    (
        SELECT OrderNumber
        FROM Table AS B
        WHERE
            B.Unique = A.Unique
    ) AS OrderNumber
FROM Table AS A
```

#### Source Table

```
+----------+-----------+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+
|  Unique  |  Weight   |     ProductionDate      | OrderNumber | ProductCode |
+----------+-----------+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+
| 14962904 |  1.920000 | 2020-06-05 11:43:12.000 |             | ABC123      |
| 14962905 |  1.990000 | 2020-06-05 11:43:14.000 |             | ABC123      |
| 14962906 |  2.020000 | 2020-06-05 11:43:20.000 |             | ABC123      |
| 14962909 |  2.030000 | 2020-06-05 11:45:09.000 |             | ABC123      |
| 14962909 | -2.030000 | 2020-06-05 11:45:09.000 |      431723 | ABC123      |
| 14962910 |  2.020000 | 2020-06-05 11:45:15.000 |             | ABC123      |
| 14962910 | -2.020000 | 2020-06-05 11:45:15.000 |      431723 | ABC123      |
| 14962911 |  1.990000 | 2020-06-05 11:45:24.000 |             | ABC123      |
| 14962911 | -1.990000 | 2020-06-05 11:45:24.000 |      431723 | ABC123      |
+----------+-----------+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+
```

#### Desired Results

```
+----------+-----------+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+
|  Unique  |  Weight   |     ProductionDate      | OrderNumber | ProductCode |
+----------+-----------+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+
| 14962904 |  1.920000 | 2020-06-05 11:43:12.000 |             | ABC123      |
| 14962905 |  1.990000 | 2020-06-05 11:43:14.000 |             | ABC123      |
| 14962906 |  2.020000 | 2020-06-05 11:43:20.000 |             | ABC123      |
| 14962909 |  2.030000 | 2020-06-05 11:45:09.000 |      431723 | ABC123      |
| 14962910 |  2.020000 | 2020-06-05 11:45:15.000 |      431723 | ABC123      |
| 14962911 |  1.990000 | 2020-06-05 11:45:24.000 |      431723 | ABC123      |
+----------+-----------+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: The _actual execution plan_ is often the place to start with query performance issues. Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be oversiùplifying this, but from your data this does look like aggregation:

```
select 
    unique,
    max(weight) weight,
    productionDate,
    max(orderNumber) orderNumber
from mtable t
group by unique, productionDate
```

Comment: I've tried to simplify it down but there are also several columns like `ProductCode` and `ProductDescription` that are just text. How can I return these without an aggregate function? Group on many columns?

Comment: I might be overthinking this, I was under the impression throwing loads of columns into the GROUP BY would slow it down, but once the unique is in there it seems to run at basically the same speed as before.

Comment: @LewisGoddard: if the values of these columns are the same across rows for a given `unique`  (like `productionDate`), then you can indeed add them in the `group by` clause. Else, well that's a pretty different assignment - we would need to see actual data to be able to tell...